# Classcast exception using javax.xml.namespace.Qname and javax.xml.ws.handler.PortInfo

Tags: java, soap, port, jax-ws, wsdl2java

I am connecting to an external WSDL using IntelliJ.

After connecting to the WSDL and generating my Java classes I am attempting to get a response from the service.

The service is not complicated at all just simple 'Yes', 'No' and 'Incorrect' message responses.

But I am getting a class cast exception involving `PortInfo` and `Qname`.

The method list call is as below.

```
 Service helloService = Service.create(
      helloWsdlUrl, 
      new QName(nameSpaceUri, serviceName));

 List list = helloService.getHandlerResolver().getHandlerChain(
      (PortInfo) new QName(nameSpaceUri, portName));

 list.add(new HandlerInfo((Class) null, (Map)null, (QName[])null));
```

And the error message I am getting is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: 
javax.xml.namespace.QName cannot be cast to javax.xml.ws.handler.PortInfo
at Client.main(Client.java:37)
```

[picture of portinfo removed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bak6D.png)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that a `QName` cannot be cast to a `PortInfo`. It is the following code that generates the error:

```
(PortInfo) new QName(...)
```

Why are you doing this cast? `getHandlerChain()` should be able to take in a `QName` instance.

Comment: getHandlerChain expects PortInfo.
I will attach a photo to the original post.

Comment: Hmm... I could've sworn I'd used a `HandlerResolver` that took `QName` in the `getHandlerChain`. You could get the `PortInfo` from the service description, or build one. All you need is a way to return the binding ID, port, and service names.

Comment: Well, how would one go about returning those in a way that wont cause a casting error.